# database design

Tags: database-design

i'm new to database design,
i'm just looking at the following two approaches to my design and just wondering if it pays to take the second approach. but again i thought that would be just making a redundant table. any suggestions on this?

**first approach:**

customer table
**----------------------------------**
customer_id - primary key
**----------------------------------**
title
first_name
last_name
cell_number
address_line1
address_line2
city
zip_code
country
**--------------------------------**

**second approach:**

customer table
**---------------------------------**
customer_id - primary key
**---------------------------------**
title
first_name
last_name
cell_number
**---------------------------------**

customer address table
**--------------------------------**
address_id - primary key
**--------------------------------**
customer_id - foreign key
address_line1
address_line2
city
zip_code
country
**---------------------------------**

***edit:** each user is allowed to have only 1 address in the database.

Comment: If a customer can have multiple addresses (#2) you may want to indicate the address type: home, work, primary, prefered, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main question is if a customer can have more than one address.

In case a customer has more than one address, the second design will be appropriate.

If each customer has only one address, you should use the first one,
for several reasons:

1. It is simpler and it's always best to keep things simple
2. Foreign keys create overhead when you use INSERT, since the DB Engine has to check all the rows of the primary key of the first table to see if the customer ID exists.
3. You'll have to use JOIN for certain queries.

Another advantage of the second design is that it has a PRIMARY KEY on the address field,
this means that the DB Engine will index this column causing SELECT queries to go
faster, however you can also create this index on the first design.

So overall, the second design is only needed if you have more than one address for each customer.

Comment: each user is allowed only 1 address. how can i create the index in the first design?

Comment: The basic SQL syntax is `CREATE INDEX index_name ON table_name (column_name)`, there are a lot more options, you should check the manual to see all of them, e.g for MySQL check this page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html, lots of luck :) (p.s bare in mind that indexes have the advantage of making SELECT statements go faster but changes to the DB will be slower)

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is only beneficial to you if you allow one user to have more than one address in your database at once, which I'm assuming is not the case, so you should go with the first approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should check [Normalization Forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms)

Then all of your questions will end :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know any companies that have more than one office?
If you intend to have them as customers, use the second approach.

Answer (score 2):

The first approach would be faster since you don't need to execute join queries when looking up the address information.

The second approach would be appropriate if you allow users to have multiple addresses.

Answer (score 2):

Things to ask yourself:

- Do I want to update the entire customer record (and possibly change customer ID) if the customer moves?
- If your customer moves, do you want to keep track of their previous addresses?
- Do your customers have multiple delivery addresses?

That should help answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Customers may also have separate billing and shipping addresses.  I've used:

```
...
billing.address_line1
billing.address_line2
...
shipping.address_line1
shipping.address_line2
...
```

If the shipping address is NULL then use the billing address.